# How can I share a PowerPoint file with NodeJS?

Tags: jsp, node.js, servlets

I have `ShowPresentation.jsp` that uploads a PPT file from computer and convert each slides to image by java servlet.

Then I need to share it in real time by NodeJS, how can I do it ?
This is `ShowPresentation.jsp` content.

```
<!DOCTYPE >
<html>
<head> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var current_slide_number = 1;
        function button(slideNumber){
            current_slide_number = current_slide_number + slideNumber;
            var image = document.getElementById('imageslide');
            var fileName = document.getElementById('hidFileName');
            image.src = 'Viewer?slideNumber='+current_slide_number+'&hidFileName='+fileName.value;
        }
    </script>
    <title>PowerPoint to JPEG</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form method="post" action="Viewer" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            <p >
                Upload a file:</p>
            <input type="file" name="datafile" size="40"> <input type="submit" value="Upload">
        </form>
    </div>
    <% if (request.getAttribute("fileName") != null) {
    %>
    <div id="slide-controls">
        <b>Please navigate through the slides</b>
```

```
</div>

<div id="slide"><p align="center">
        <img id="imageslide" src="Viewer?hidFileName=<%=request.getAttribute("fileName")%>"></img>
    </p>
</div>

<% }%>
<input id="hidFileName" type="hidden" value="<%=request.getAttribute("fileName")%>"></input>
```

and this servlet content Viewer.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.poi.hslf.model.Slide;
import org.apache.poi.hslf.usermodel.SlideShow;
public class Viewer extends HttpServlet {
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    int slideNumber = 1; 
    BufferedImage image = null;
    ServletOutputStream os = null;
    try{
        if (request.getParameter("hidFileName") != null){
            String fileName = request.getParameter("hidFileName");
        if(request.getParameter("slideNumber") != null)
            slideNumber = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("slideNumber"));
        image = getSlideAsImage(fileName, slideNumber);
        os = response.getOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpeg", os );
        }
        else {
            response.sendRedirect("StartPresentation.jsp");
        }   
    }
    catch (Exception e){
                if (os != null)
            os.close();
    }       
}
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
      String contentType = request.getContentType();
      String realPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
        if ((contentType != null) && (contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0)) 
        {
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());
            int formDataLength = request.getContentLength();
            byte dataBytes[] = new byte[formDataLength];
            int byteRead = 0;
            int totalBytesRead = 0;
            while (totalBytesRead < formDataLength) {
                byteRead = in.read(dataBytes, totalBytesRead, formDataLength);
                totalBytesRead += byteRead;
            }
            String file = new String(dataBytes);
            String saveFile = file.substring(file.indexOf("filename=\"") + 10);
            saveFile = saveFile.substring(0, saveFile.indexOf("\n"));
            saveFile = saveFile.substring(saveFile.lastIndexOf("\\")+ 1, saveFile.indexOf("\""));
            int lastIndex = contentType.lastIndexOf("=");
            String boundary = contentType.substring(lastIndex + 1, contentType.length());
            int pos;
            pos = file.indexOf("filename=\"");
            pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
            pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
            pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
            int boundaryLocation = file.indexOf(boundary, pos) - 4;
            int startPos = ((file.substring(0, pos)).getBytes()).length;
            int endPos = ((file.substring(0, boundaryLocation)).getBytes()).length;
            System.out.println("After File Name: "+ saveFile);
            String filePath = realPath + "/" +  saveFile;
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
            fileOut.write(dataBytes, startPos, (endPos - startPos));
            fileOut.close();
            request.setAttribute("fileName", saveFile);
            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/StartPresentation.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
}
private BufferedImage getSlideAsImage(String fileName, int slideNumber) throws Exception
{
    BufferedImage image = null; 
    String realPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
    String filePath = realPath + "/" + fileName;
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    SlideShow ppt = new SlideShow(in);
    Slide[] slides = ppt.getSlides();
    Dimension pgsize = ppt.getPageSize();
    image = new BufferedImage(pgsize.width, pgsize.height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D graphics = image.createGraphics();
    graphics.setPaint(Color.white);
    graphics.fill(new Rectangle2D.Float(0, 0, pgsize.width, pgsize.height));
    if (slideNumber < 1)
        slideNumber = 1;
    else if (slideNumber > slides.length)
        slideNumber = slides.length;
    slides[slideNumber - 1].draw(graphics);
    return image;
}
```

}

Comment: Share what you're tried. We can't guess what you've done, or what errors you're getting. Also we won't write the whole thing for you.

Comment: You look very new to the forum, in order to help you better you have to make your question little elaborative and more realistic. Try it and then you will get the best of the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need nodejs at all? If they're just static files after they've been converted, why not just serve the image files with a static asset server e.g. nginx?

Sounds like you just need a static assert server. If you want to use node to do this, [http-server](https://github.com/nodeapps/http-server) will do the job for now:

```
npm install -g http-server
cd my/assets
sudo http-server -p 80 &
```

Then go to http://localhost in your web browser.

Comment: @Sara: can you share what knowledge you do have?

Comment: the first command its ok, but the seconde command show me this -bash: cd: my/assets: No such file or directory

Comment: @Sara, you need to 'change directory' (cd) to the directory your assets are in, then run the http-server.

Comment: @timoxley thank you, when i go to folder that contain assets and run `sudo http-server -p 80 &`, this appear at terminal  `[1] 2624`, and nothing at localhost, are `my` my project floder ?

Comment: run kill 2624. and yes, my is your project folder. Not sure what the issue is, sorry!

Comment: `Starting up http-server, serving ./ on port: 80 ` is this true ??where i go now ? loacalhost:/ShowPresentstion.jsp ?